# Pointer getter to a reference

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, getter

I have a class with a reference and want a getter that returns a pointer.

```
class X {
    std::string& text;
public:
    auto GetText() -> decltype(text) * { return &text); // doesn't work
    X(std::string& text): text(text) {}
};
```

The easy way is to pass a pointer to this class. But if I pass a reference, can I get a pointer with a getter?

**Edit:** here is the error message

```
error: cannot declare pointer to 'std::__cxx11::string& {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}'
auto GetText() -> decltype(text) * { return &text);
                                 ^
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Do you get compile errors? If so, please put them in your question.

Comment: Why not just do `std::string* GetText() { return &text; }`? Also your code has typos (surely you meant `}` instead of `)` to close that function).
`

Comment: You're mixing up too many things

Comment: All this seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: That's what happens when you take idle watercooler talk of "always auto" literally and just run with it without any reflection at all.

Comment: `auto` is good and all, but you want interfaces to be stable. Breaking API compatibility as soon as you change an implementation detail is not good.

Comment: @cornstalks OK, the old way works. But I thought that `decltype(text)` is here the same as std::string and if I add a `*` that this should be the same as the old way? But it's not. Why?

Comment: @bais `decltype(text)` is `std::string&`, not `std::string`. You can't declare a pointer-to-reference type (not to be confused with calculating the *address* of a referenced object, which you *can* do, and evaluates to the address of the referenced entity). reference-to-pointer-type is allowed, pointer-to-reference-type is *not*, demonstrated by a [simpler example **here**](http://ideone.com/A0jeP6).

Comment: @WhozCraig `auto GetText() { return &text; }` works too. But does this all mean I can not write something with `auto` AND `decltype` here? There is no way?

Comment: You can if you [strip the reference](http://ideone.com/WlIiix), but why would you want to? As Kerrek said, all of this seems completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,

```
auto GetText() -> decltype(text) * { return &text); // doesn't work
```

is a positively abominable way to declare this signature. Prefer

```
std::string* GetText(){ return &text);
```

or even just

```
auto GetText(){ return &text);
```

But this isn't code review.

The problem here is that you're asking for a pointer to the declared type of the `text` member variable which is a string reference (`std::string&`). From the comment section, it seems you were unaware that `decltype` respects the 'reference'ness, 'const'ness, and 'volatile'ness of its argument.

You cannot have a pointer to a reference in C++, e.g. `std::string&*` is malformed. Calling to [std::remove_reference_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) should resolve that issue, e.g.

```
auto GetText() -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text)> * { return &text);
```

However, in this case, `auto` would have correctly deduced your type anyway, so your explicit declaration is unnecessary.

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a  [test program](http://ideone.com/TXci8L) for my initial problem. The program has a class with a pointer and a getter that returns a reference and a second class with a reference and a getter that returns a pointer.

And it seems that `-> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text)>` can be substituted with `-> decltype(&text)`.

Feel free to comment.

```
// g++ main.cpp -o test_reference_pointer && strip -s test_reference_pointer && ./test_reference_pointer

#include <iostream>

// A class with a pointer and a getter that returns a reference.
class A {
    std::string *text;
public:
    std::string& GetText_old_way() { return *text; }
    auto GetText_pure_auto() { return *text; }
    auto GetText_pointer_arithmetic() -> decltype(*text) & { return *text; }
public:
    A(std::string *text): text(text) {}
};

// A class with a reference and a getter that returns a pointer.
class B {
    std::string& text;
public:
    std::string *GetText_old_way() { return &text; }
    auto GetText_pure_auto() { return &text; }
    auto GetText_pointer_arithmetic() -> decltype(&text) { return &text; }
    auto GetText_remove_reference() -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text)> * { return &text; }
public:
    B(std::string& text): text(text) {}
};

int main() {
    std::string text = "hello, world";

    {//TEST
        A a(&text);
        unsigned int i{0};

        std::cout << "-- Test 1:"<< std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << a.GetText_old_way() << std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << a.GetText_pointer_arithmetic() << std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << a.GetText_pure_auto() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    {//TEST
        B b(text);
        unsigned int i{0};

        std::cout << "-- Test 2:"<< std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << *b.GetText_old_way() << std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << *b.GetText_pointer_arithmetic() << std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << *b.GetText_remove_reference() << std::endl;
        ++i; std::cout << i << ". " << *b.GetText_pure_auto() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note in class `A`, `GetText_pure_auto` is returning a copy of the underlying string rather than reference, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: In class `A`, in `auto GetText_pointer_arithmetic`, the trailing `&` of `decltype(*text)&` is unnecessary; `decltype(*text)` is equivalent. More over, if you're using C++14, this signature may be written more compactly as `decltype(*text) GetText_pointer_arithmetic()` or `decltype(auto)` or `auto&`

Comment: "And it seems that -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text)> can be substituted with -> decltype(&text)" You're slightly mistaken. `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text)>*` may be replaced by `decltype(&text)` in this case, not `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(text)>`

Comment: @ampccartney Why is `auto GetText_pointer_arithmetic() -> decltype(*text) { return *text; }` the same as `auto GetText_pointer_arithmetic() -> decltype(*text) & { return *text; }`? The first looks like it returns a `std::string` and not a `std::string&`.

Comment: You understand that when you dereference a pointer, the result type is a reference, correct?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. But it sounds like 'dereference a pointer' in C means 'remove pointer == get the value' and in C++ it means 'remove pointer == get the value (through a reference)'. I missed the brackets of C++ :-)